# Dynamics CRM - Importing a Solution with Client Extensions (Site Map) doesn't remove entries

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Unmanaged solutions, not managed.

Let's say you deployed a Site Map previously (Client Extensions item in a solution) that had a link to entity ABC.

It was started in Dev and exported/imported all the way to Prod.

Now you want to remove it. So you remove "ABC" from the Site Map in Dev, then export/import to Prod.

PROBLEM: it didn't remove entry "ABC" in Prod despite it being removed in Dev and exported/imported that way.

Is this documented/intentional behavior? Are Client Extensions/Site Maps only additive and don't remove entries in Solutions? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing/exporting unmanaged solutions?

If you're importing as unmanaged then it's likely the customizations to the sitemap are being applied over the existing unmanaged layer in the target environment, and like you said, additive only.

From a previously deployed unmanaged solution, if you remove an entity and redeploy, that entity will remain in the target system. Likely that same behaviour is applying to the site map layering.

Try exporting the site map as part of a managed solution. This *might* help, although I can't make any promises. We have experienced odd behaviour with sitemaps that exist in multiple managed solution layers. So depending on your configuration this may or may not be helpful.

I found the most reliable way to manage a site map is in a single managed solution that sits at the top of the solution layers.